# How core data lightweight migration deals with different persistent stores?

Tags: xcode, core-data, migration

Suppose I have 1 model with configurations: A and B

Target 1 uses configuration A
Target 2 uses configuration B

What happens if I change an Entity on configuration A and run Target B?

Will the process of migration look for the entire model or just check the existing entities in the configuration that's running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Configurations are twitchy.  If you are trying to switch from one configuration to another then it will be difficult as there is no clear migration path.

If you are looking to migration configuration A to a new version of configuration A that is a bit more straight forward.  You need to migrate each `NSPersistentStore` individually.

I generally stand them up in a throw away `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` and deal with the migration.  Make sure you specify the configuration even when you are using them in a throw away `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` otherwise things will get confused.

Once all the stores are migrated, then I stand up the permanent `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`.  I never handle migration in the final coordinator.

If you are trying to merge two configurations back into a single store then you are going to run into issues and will probably need to do a manual migration (export/import).

Comment: very elucidative! I was just trying to avoid the migration, when changing just the part of the model that is not being used by the current target. in other words, I thought there would be no migration if only part of the model was modified, in this case, the configuration not used by the current target.

Comment: What I'm perceiving now is that the store (for any configuration) stores the complete set of metadata from the model it derives.

Comment: Yes it does and it is up to you to keep track of which stores are using which configuration.